# Problem with Multiple Screen Size for Google and Generic Phones

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to program an app which supports multiple screen sizes. For each layout, I created layout, layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large and layout-xlarge file. The problem is, that the Google phones with 5 inch will be assigned to the layout-normal but this shouldn't. Phones from 3.2 inches up to 6 inches are assign to layout-normal. How can I change this or make this in the correct way?

Here you can see some Images of my problem:
I tried it also with layout-sw320dp, layout-sw480dp and so on, but the problem is the same.

Comment: Using external library is ok with you?

Comment: It's possible, but I don't believe that it is not possible just using android studio without any external library. This should be standard to use easily layouts for multiple screen sizes. I'm not sure if I'm to dump for this or if the problem is on the side of android studio...

Comment: Search ssp and sdp lib in GitHub, I have used it, it is very handy

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved my Problem :)

Comment: Welcome Happy to help